# How to show level from Django MPTTModel in template?

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates, django-mptt

I'm using `django-mptt` to store a  hierarchical data (A Story with a number of scenes, in which  each scene is a child of another scene) in DB.   The data is for each node(scene) is collected from the user using a form. When the user is adding data to the form I like to show which level the current node is going to be saved.

This is my model

```
class Scene(MPTTModel, models.Model):
    story_id = models.ForeignKey(Story, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    choice1 = models.TextField(max_length=1000, default=None)
    choice2 = models.TextField(max_length=1000, default=None)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['id']
```

My `forms.py`

```
class SceneForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Scenario
        fields = ['description','choice1', 'choice2']
        readonly_fields = ['level']
```

My `scene.html`

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <h2>Create scene for Level {{form.level}}</h2>
    <h1>{{ form.title }}</h1>
    <p>{{ form.desc }}</p>
    <form class="scenario-designer" action="{% url 'App:designscene' %}" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <table>
        {{form.as_table}}
      </table>
      <button type="submit" name="save" value="save">Save</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

The `level` is not showing, when I try `form.level` in debug console it shows `AttributeError: 'SceneForm' object has no attribute 'level'`. I was under the impression that since `MPTTModel` have `level` field it could be accessed using `form.`. Any pointers on how to access the `level` attribute in the template is greatly appriciated. I'm very new to django so please forgive my lack of understanding.